# Specify which emacs to open for a file when running shell inside emacs

Tags: shell

Consider a scenario

- I run an emacs instance **E01**, and use the shell inside emacs to find the file I want to open;
- I found the file `file` using this shell. Now I'm ready to open it through the shell command `emacs file`.
- This `file` is now open in a **new** emacs instance **E02**, different from the one where the shell runs.

And My question is, for the second step of my scenario, when I try opening the file using `emacs file`, how to use the same emacs instance (i.e. **E01** in this case) for it?

Comment: Normally you would simply `C-x C-f <file>` as you're already inside Emacs.  Is there some reason why that's not a suitable solution for you?  The shell buffer will usually be tracking the current directory for the shell, so `find-file` and `dired` and so on will default to that directory.

Comment: Failing that, all I can suggest is that you run Emacs as a server and get into the habit of using `emacsclient` instead of `emacs` on the command line.  The 'problem' you're seeing (that running `emacs` starts a new instance) is 100% expected behaviour.

Comment: Hi Phils, thanks for your comment. Yeah, it's definitely good to `fine-file`. I considered it not an optimal solution because sometimes I depends on the shell to call specific commands for tasks say building a binary, and I normally would try different 'build options' by modifying many configuration files. If I could just use this shell to call commands to open the file and do quick modification, it'll be much more comfortable and consistent to me as I don't need to 'switch my mindset' between 'emacs' and 'shell'.

Comment: Regarding the `emacsclient`, I'd give it a try!